# Using static variables to store user info on Android

Tags: android

I'm making an android app which has to frequently call some .net web services using the kSoap2 library. The user has to log in each time the app is launched (a decision that is out of my hands). I have one class which calls the web services. Each web service requires a username, a password and one other data string to access it. When the user successfully logs in I store the correct username, password and other piece of data in 3 private static variables inside the web services class, to use when I need to call other web services.

Could this approach end up being problematic down the road?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could this approach end up being problematic down the road?

I don't see why this would be a problem.

As for Ralgha's answer, Shared preferences persist your login information to an XML file. If the user must login to the application every time anyway, it defeats the purpose of the shared preference. You are better off keeping this data in memory.

The VM cannot GC any static variable you hold a reference to. So the data will not be GCed. Other applications cannot read in to your memory either. Sounds all right to me.

Comment: You're not considering that, according to the activity lifecycle, the system may destroy the process due to low memory and the values of these static variables will be wiped away.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html), sounds like exactly what you need.  Static variables are generally bad programming form.

Comment: I always thought SharedPreferences could be accessed if the device is rooted?

Comment: Probably, lots of things can be accessed if it's rooted.  Does it matter?  That's probably a question everyone has to answer for themselves.  I think most developers answer it with a "no."

Comment: If your device is rooted the user can open the folder with the SharedPreferences XML. That's right.

Comment: Oops I missed the part where they are required to log in every time.  SharedPreferences aren't needed then, go with Deepak's answer.